# System.DIINotFoundException: Failed to find library “leptonica-1.80.0.dll” for platform x86

Tags: winforms, selenium-webdriver, dll, tesseract

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no WinForms usando o OCR Tesseract, sempre que executo a aplicação em localhost funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu publico ou mando a pasta `bin` para outro computador aparece o seguinte erro:

```
System.DIINotFoundException: Failed to find library "leptonica-1.80.0.dll" for platform x86.

in InteropDotNet.LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary(String fileName, String platformName)

in
Interop Runtimelmplementer.LeptonicaApiSignaturesInstance.Leptonica ApiSignaturesImplementation..ctor(LibraryLoader loader)
```

1. Eu já tentei mover para a pasta `myproject\packages\Tesseract.4.1.1\lib\net45\leptonika-1.80.0.dll` sem sucesso.
2. Já verifiquei as versões do .NET
3. Já tentei instalar o pacote do tesseract na pasta bin do projeto